# TortoiseSVN log only shown for one day?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I've re-install TortoiseSVN 1.10 after migrating to new laptop. Now it only shows the log for one day (today). Is this a new setting?

How can I configuration it to show at least one month?

[image: TortoiseSVN log only shown one day]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> TortoiseSVN log only show for 1 day?

It shows the log for one day just because you selected only one day in the **From** and **To** fields on the top right of the **Log Messages** window. Adjust the date range and click **Show All** or **Next 100**.

Comment: thanks for reply, the folder in my picture only have some commit, when I check the root, it shows all.